# Como autocompletar tag php no netBeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

sou iniciante em PHP e gostaria de saber como fazer o netBeans autocompletar a tag `<?php ?>`pois toda vez tenho que escrever a tag toda e isso está me enchendo (no SublimeText ele escreve, só que prefiro o NetBeans por causa que ele exibi uma lista de variáveis após o cifrão).

[image: Como autocompletar esta tag?]

Comment: Use Atom Github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O NetBeans não completa por padrão esse código, para isso terá que adicionar manualmente o modelo de código.

No NetBeans clique em:

> Ferramentas > Opções > Editor > Modelos de Código

Escolha a linguagem **HTML** pois é esta que está sendo usada até colocar a tag do PHP.

Clique em **Novo**, digite qual é o atalho que quer que autocomplete, por exemplo `php`, clique em **OK**.

Na próxima tela insira o código que você quer que autocomplete quando escrever `php`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php ?>
```

Em **Expandir Modelo em:** selecione a tecla que você quer acionar o autocompletar, por exemplo: <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Clique em **OK**.

Quando for testar coloque o atalho que no meu caso foi `php` e depois pressione <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> "And see the Magic!"

Para mais informações: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/code-templates_pt_BR.html